# My wordpress custom post displays the content rather than the excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made a custom post type called 'news', plus an index page called 'archive-news'. In the archive page the excerpt is replaced with the content of the post. Can't work out how to change it.

I've been using HTML for over a year, familiar with the idea of Wordpress PHP but probably not deep enough yet. Had a look for similar problems. The input area for the excerpt has not been left blank (when you edit a custom post). I've heard that if it doesn't then it defaults to use content instead of excerpt. Cleared the cache many times and given it time to refresh.

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="postExcerpt">           
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>          

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

should show the excerpt and not the content in the archive-news

Comment: Try using `<?= get_the_excerpt() ?>` and see what that returns. Also, does your custom post type include `excerpt` in the list of things it supports? Ie, `'supports' => ['excerpt']`

Comment: yes the supports excerpt is checked in the CPT UI plugin, the get excerpt returns nothing with no errors

Comment: Hmm, not used that plugin, but I assume it's applied the support correctly! What does `var_dump($post->post_excerpt);` return?

Comment: How long is the post content?  Is it less than 55 words?  In this case it will show the full content.

Comment: var_dump shows the post excerpt plus the length as a string! the_content is still showing.

Comment: I've lengthened the content to way over 55 words and its still showing the content rather than the excerpt

Comment: ok! when you had <?= get_the_excerpt() ?> I didn't realise that it was a shorthand for the <?php tag. I used your line of code benJ and it works!!! many thanks plus I learned about the var_dump. Many thanks everyone!